# Is there a way to iterate through a string to return the first, last, and middle names of an array in Ruby?

Tags: html, arrays, ruby, iteration, command-line-interface

I'm working on a command-line interface and scraping a website to return a list of names. I'm having trouble separating the First, Middle, and Last names of the HTML output. I've narrowed it down to this:

```
name = doc.css("h2 a").text.strip.split.join(' ')
```

This returns:

```
Karina CAPS Jeffery M. CAPS Terry M. CAPS Zaid F. CAPS Abdalmahd CAPS Aziz CAPS Jason V. CAPS Patrick R. CAPS Nancy A. CAPS Henry L. CAPS Floyd CAPS
```

etc.. for a total of 20 names.

The last names can remain capitalized but I need to separate the names properly because I'm going to eventually list the names by index +1. With code like this:

```
@people.each.with_index(1) do |person, i|
  puts "#{i}. #{person.name}"
end
```

Any ideas???

Comment: What is CAPS? Is that a last name? And is there a way to get each name individually through a selector? What's the HTML structure like.

Comment: CAPS is just my way of protecting their last names. They're listed alphabetically. There is a way to get each name individually, I tried doing `doc.css("h2 a").children[index where a name is].text ` and it outputs the full name but I need to be able to output all of them and separate them by **1. Name 2. Name**, etc. They're all on the same page, with the same headers & class

Comment: Why are you mashing them all together into a single string? You should keep them separate. If you're using Nokogiri's `css` selector you can get an array of matching elements.

Comment: @tadman Haha, the goal is to not have them mashed together. I don't want to create a method for each name, so I'm trying to figure out a way to iterate over each so the user can enter a number and my program outputs `#{i}. #{name}` accordingly.

Comment: Right, so you want to do something like `names = doc.css('h2 a').map { |e| e.text.strip }` where you can then rework that as you see fit into `@people` objects.

Comment: @tadman Wow thank you! That helped me a lot. That line returned an array and ordered the names properly. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking to extract the names you can just `map` the elements that match:

```
names = doc.css('h2 a').map { |e| e.text.strip }
```

Where `map` allows you to do a little work on each one to prepare them before putting them in the final array.